# How to show file content in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my own To-Do list for that I need to display the content of a file. The problem is that i don't want to select the file and want the content to be displayed directly. Can anyone help me?
(I want to display the content of a .txt file on a html side without selecting the file(so just in the source code))

Comment: Is this file a .txt file?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do note that this is not a general help forum. Please provide some more details about your problem so that users may better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileReader` for reading the content of the text file:

```js
document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var fr=new FileReader();
    fr.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('output').textContent=fr.result;
      }
              
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  })
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
<br>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript/